# How to pass values to c# parameters starting with @

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, url, parameter-passing

Trying to pass the values but not making progress.

Scenario : Have a public constant string as below.

```
public const string ImageFile = @"http://xyz.com/scom/{0}?type={1}&wid={2}";
```

I will then get the relevant values required for 0,1,2 that is required for above.

Question is how do I pass the values I have for 0,1,2 to the above const string?

My end result should be something like

```
string mySTring = "http://xyz.com/scom/123?type=jpg&wid=200"
```

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you know the syntax for `string.Format` (i.e. `{0}`) without knowing about `string.Format`?

Comment: @KirlWoll - Methods like `Console.WriteLine` allow for composite formatting.  In other words, `string.format` can be used implicitly in many if not most cases.  Many developers can use string.format and never even know it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Comment: I once encountered a major performance issue because someone knew all about vfprintf, but had no idea sprintf existed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `String.Format`:

```
string ActualImageFile = String.Format(ImageFile, param1, param2, param3);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Format(@"http://xyz.com/scom/{0}?type={1}&wid={2}", param1, param2, param3);
```

Should do the trick.